# How to specialize template class without parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

I have such code, but compiler says about error (error C2913: explicit specialization; 'Vector' is not a specialization of a class template d:\test_folder\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp  28  1   ConsoleApplication1
):

```
#include <iostream>

template <int N, int ... T>
class Vector
{
public:
    static void print_arguments(void)
    {
        std::cout << N << " : " << std::endl;
        Vector<T>::print_argumetns();
    }
protected:
private:
};

template <>
class Vector<>
{
public:
    static void print_arguments(void)
    {
    }
protected:
private:
};

int main(void)
{
   std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
   int i = 0;
   std::cin >> i;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: without parameters it isnt a specialization, I would rather call it a "generalization" which isnt possible afaik

Comment: In other words, I cannot create template without any parameters?

Comment: I dont understand, why you want to do this? How is this supposed to be used?

Comment: For educational purposes, I just wanted to create class, which will print own arguments in sorted order

Comment: turns out, that I was wrong, see Tartans answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't create a specialization of `Vector` with no template parameters, because `Vector` requires at least one.

What you can do instead is declare the primary template to take any number of template arguments, then define both cases as specializations:

```
//primary template
template <int... Ns>
class Vector;

//this is now a specialization
template <int N, int ... T>
class Vector<N,T...>
{
    //...
};

template <>
class Vector<>
{
    //...
};
```

Comment: Great! thanks, but I cannot understand, why this version of code works. Can you give me some links to explanations, please?

Comment: What do you not understand in particular?

Comment: Why primary template declaration is needed?

Comment: Because if you don't have one, `Vector` is a class template which *needs* at least one template argument. With the primary template, `Vector` is a class template which can have any number of template arguments and there are specializations for when there are none and when there is at least one.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that I understood

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is this:

```
template <int N, int ... T>
class Vector
{
public:
    static void print_arguments(void)
    {
        std::cout << N << " : " << std::endl;
        Vector<T...>::print_arguments();
    }
protected:
private:
};

template <int N>
class Vector<N>
{
public:
    static void print_arguments(void)
    {
        std::cout << N << " : " << std::endl;
    }
protected:
private:
};
```

The second is a "terminating" partial specialization, which is used when only one parameter is used.

Comment: This version will not work in such case, I guess : 

    Vector<> vector;

Comment: Yes, the TartanLlama version is better as it works even in that case, the general idea is the same.